# Problem of crashing command on "lightningd/lightningd --network=testnet --log-level=debug"

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, blockchain.info, lightning-network

When I try running the "lightningd/lightningd --network=testnet --log-level=debug" after sucessfully starting the Bitcoin server using the "bitcoind -daemon -testnet" ,following issue occurs:

lightningd/lightningd --network=testnet --log-level=debug
2018-02-12T12:34:40.313Z lightningd(14966): Trying to guess public addresses...
2018-02-12T12:34:40.313Z lightningd(14966): Address 192.168.0.73:9735 is not routable
2018-02-12T12:34:40.313Z lightningd(14966): Failed to connect 10 socket: Network is unreachable
2018-02-12T12:34:40.313Z lightningd(14966): testing /home/blockchain/lightning/lightningd/lightning_channeld
2018-02-12T12:34:40.314Z lightningd(14966): testing /home/blockchain/lightning/lightningd/lightning_closingd
2018-02-12T12:34:40.314Z lightningd(14966): testing /home/blockchain/lightning/lightningd/lightning_gossipd
2018-02-12T12:34:40.315Z lightningd(14966): testing /home/blockchain/lightning/lightningd/lightning_hsmd
2018-02-12T12:34:40.315Z lightningd(14966): testing /home/blockchain/lightning/lightningd/lightning_onchaind
2018-02-12T12:34:40.316Z lightningd(14966): testing /home/blockchain/lightning/lightningd/lightning_openingd
2018-02-12T12:34:40.471Z lightningd(14966): Client: Received message 11 from client
2018-02-12T12:34:40.480Z lightningd(14966): Loaded 0 invoices from DB
2018-02-12T12:34:40.480Z lightningd(14966): Client: Received message 9 from client
2018-02-12T12:34:40.480Z lightning_gossipd(14974): pid 14974, msgfd 12
2018-02-12T12:34:40.481Z lightningd(14966): Loaded 0 channels from DB
bitcoin-cli exited with code 1: error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and no rpcpassword is set in the configuration file (/home/lightning/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)

2018-02-12T12:34:40.518Z lightningd(14966): bitcoin-cli exited with code 1: error: Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and no rpcpassword is set in the configuration file (/home/lightning/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)

Log dumped in crash.log
2018-02-12T12:34:40.545Z lightningd(14966): FATAL SIGNAL 6 RECEIVED
2018-02-12T12:34:40.548Z lightningd(14966): backtrace: lightningd/log.c:486 (log_crash) 0x410b18
2018-02-12T12:34:40.561Z lightningd(14966): backtrace: (null):0 ((null)) 0x7fc0b7dc24af
2018-02-12T12:34:40.561Z lightningd(14966): backtrace: (null):0 ((null)) 0x7fc0b7dc2428
2018-02-12T12:34:40.561Z lightningd(14966): backtrace: (null):0 ((null)) 0x7fc0b7dc4029
2018-02-12T12:34:40.561Z lightningd(14966): backtrace: lightningd/log.c:575 (fatal) 0x410f52
2018-02-12T12:34:40.561Z lightningd(14966): backtrace: lightningd/bitcoind.c:723 (wait_for_bitcoind) 0x4056c9
2018-02-12T12:34:40.562Z lightningd(14966): backtrace: lightningd/chaintopology.c:723 (setup_topology) 0x407bd8
2018-02-12T12:34:40.562Z lightningd(14966): backtrace: lightningd/lightningd.c:331 (main) 0x40f258
2018-02-12T12:34:40.562Z lightningd(14966): backtrace: (null):0 ((null)) 0x7fc0b7dad82f
2018-02-12T12:34:40.562Z lightningd(14966): backtrace: (null):0 ((null)) 0x403248
2018-02-12T12:34:40.562Z lightningd(14966): backtrace: (null):0 ((null)) 0xffffffffffffffff
Fatal signal 6. 0x410bfe log_crash
    lightningd/log.c:512
0x7fc0b7dc24af ???
    ???:0
0x7fc0b7dc2428 ???
    ???:0
0x7fc0b7dc4029 ???
    ???:0
0x410f52 fatal
    lightningd/log.c:575
0x4056c9 wait_for_bitcoind
    lightningd/bitcoind.c:723
0x407bd8 setup_topology
    lightningd/chaintopology.c:723
0x40f258 main
    lightningd/lightningd.c:331
0x7fc0b7dad82f ???
    ???:0
0x403248 ???
    ???:0
0xffffffffffffffff ???
    ???:0
Log dumped in crash.log
Aborted (core dumped)

Can anybody please solve my issue and explain me what is exactly happening!

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be contained in the error message.

`Could not locate RPC credentials. No authentication cookie could be found, and no rpcpassword is set in the configuration file (/home/lightning/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf)`

So, set rpcuser and rpcpassword appropriately in `~/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`.